# Start and Stop JUnit Scripts from an SWT composite window

Tags: java, junit, swt

I am simply trying to run and stop a script (which has an infinite loop) from an SWT composite window:

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/mv3p81.png]

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(750, 500);
    shell.setLayout(new RowLayout());

    shell.setText("Up-time Script");

    final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);

//BUTTON START SCRIPT
    Button btnNewButton = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            //ParameterizedEnterZipCodeAndOk(5);
            org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(EnterZipCodeAndOk.class);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(52, 387, 75, 25);
    //toolkit.adapt(btnNewButton, true, true);
    btnNewButton.setText("Start Script");
//BUTTON STOP SCRIPT    
    Button btnStopScript = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    btnStopScript.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    btnStopScript.setBounds(163, 387, 75, 25);
    //toolkit.adapt(btnStopScript, true, true);
    btnStopScript.setText("Stop Script");
//TEXT VIEWER BOX       
    TextViewer textViewer = new TextViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER);
    StyledText styledText = textViewer.getTextWidget();
    styledText.setBounds(10, 34, 700, 347);

    Console cons;
    //cons.readLine()
     if ((cons = System.console()) != null) {
         styledText.setText(cons.readLine());

     }
    //TextConsolePage tcp = new TextConsolePage(TextConsole console,composite);

    //styledText.setText("");
    //toolkit.paintBordersFor(styledText);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();

}
```

From the button listener, I have:

`org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(EnterZipCodeAndOk.class);` which runs the JUnit test.

Is there a way to make this a parameterized run and have my stop script button set the while iterator to zero and stop the loop?

Also the Composite window stops responding when I start my script, how can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Your code is running the tests in the User Interface thread so the UI will be unresponsive while they run - you must use a separate Thread to run the tests.

Comment: BTW, you should use a SelectionListener instead of a MouseListener. Selection is fired when a button is pressed according to the rules of the platform.